# Gradle Dependencies

Tags: java, json, gradle, javafx, simplejson

I'm trying to use JSON Simple to parse a JSON file into Java in a Gradle JavaFX project.

I've tried a few things:

1. Adding `implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'` to the `build.gradle` file. ... Won't let me do `import org.json.simple.JSONParser;`

Error: `error: package org.json.simple does not exist`

2. Adding `implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'` to the `build.gradle` file. ... gives same error as above.
3. In IntelliJ, I've tried manually downloading and adding the jar file:

First I added a new directory to the root called 'libs' and added the jar file there. Went to File > Project Structure > Libraries > '+' > Java, selected the file and pressed the module I wanted to add it to. Then I added `requires json.simple;` into the `module-info.java` file.

IntelliJ does not come up with any errors, but when I do `gradle run`, it comes up with an error in the `modules-info.java` file that says `error: module not found: json.simple`

I have no idea why that last error is happening, I made sure the module was applied to the root as well (Where the `modules-info.java` file is.

I've tried `gradle clean`, invalidating caches and removing caches altogether.

If anyone knows why this issue is occuring (or can suggest another way I can parse a JSON file), that would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have just tried to add dependency on JSON.simple to my project and it works... there must be something wrong with your gradle project - but cannot determine what is actually wrong without a snippet of your build.gradle file. Json.simple is dead (last release 2012) so btw. I recommend to use jackson instead - https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson.

Comment: Thanks Eduard, I’ll check Jackson. I just did Gradle Init and added the dependency to it straight away so there can’t be anything wrong with it. My uni made me downgrade to Java 11, not sure if that is causing any issues but I’ll see if Jackson works :)